# Create Dictionary Symbology in ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcade, dictionary, arcgis-field-maps

After some struggling I have been able to create my own dynamic symbols using the Dictionary Symbology in ArcGIS Pro. It does exactly what I want, stacking different symbols based on attribute values with the help of Arcade.

Is it possible to create the same symbology in ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise, and also get this out to Field Maps?

Here is a sample of what I want the map to look like:
[image: Map with "stacked symbols"]

Comment: These are some points over ESRI Basemap, symbolized using these shapes? And you want this symbology in ArcGIS Online to be used in field maps?

Comment: Yes @Yogi, I would like them to be displayed in Field Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sharing the Dictionary Symbology as a Web Style: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/share-a-web-style.htm?

But note that has some limitations:

- ***When sharing 2D styles, the symbol is a point, a line, a polygon, or text. All other style items are unsupported.***

I believe sharing and web rendering of dictionary symbology is still very much in Beta and has a number of limitations. See this: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-DictionaryRenderer.html

**Known Limitations**

DictionaryRenderer may only be used to create visualizations for the following layer types:

- FeatureLayer
- CSVLayer
- GeoJSONLayer
- OGCFeatureLayer
- WFSLayer
- StreamLayer

**DictionaryRenderer is not supported in the Legend widget.**

These were all big limitations for me when I tried this.  I had set up my Dictionary in Pro with lots of image markers, and I don't think I could publish those as a Web Style, then of course it didn't show up the Legend in apps, so that was frustrating, but I recently had to try again for another project, so maybe it has improved.